# Reverse an int using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I want to reverse an int but it doesn't work. For example, 123 should return 321, but the printed number is 356.

```
public class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverse2(123, 0));
    }
    
    static int reverse2(int a, int i) {
        if(a == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            i = i*10 + a%10;
            System.out.println(i); 
            return i += reverse2(a/10, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i = i*10 + a%10;` Why?

Comment: You don't need two `int`s in your `reverse2` function if you want to create a "print reverse integer" function using recursion. It looks like you know how to get the rightmost digit with the `% 10` trick, so why all the excess complication? Just do `% 10` to get the rightmost digit and `/ 10` to shift the number before calling the recursive function again.

Comment: sorry but i don't know how to use only one int, and i make the line i = i*10 + a%10; base on the tutorial which uses for loop

Comment: @dan1st i make it base on the tutorial which uses for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
public class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverse2(123, 0));
    }

    static int reverse2(int a, int i) {
        if(a == 0) {
            return i;
        } else {
            i = i*10 + a%10;
            System.out.println(i); 
            return reverse2(a/10, i);
        }
    }
}
```

You should return `i` when a is `0`.

You shouldn't add `i` when you call the `reverse2` function because you're adding `i` twice.

Comment: i have tried this way, but i just want to ask why my code doesn't work. It did print 321, and then 356, the difference was 35 and there is no i value that match 35

Comment: Your code is not working because when u do `return i += reverse2(a/10, i);` you re adding in each call 3 + 32 + 321 = 356. You dont need to keep the value in `i` once you re sending that value via parameters

Answer (score 0):

You are greatly complicating your recursive function for printing an integer in reverse. For one, there is no good reason for `reverse2` to have two integer arguments, as you can achieve your desired results with a single argument. The trick is to access the rightmost digit with the `% 10` operation then shift that digit off the number with the `/ 10` operation. Consider these revisions:

```java
public class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverse2(123));
    }
    
    static String reverse2(int number) {
        if(number == 0) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return number % 10 + reverse2(number / 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to print the whole number, the print used in the method is to check the value of i only

Comment: @YSJR Very well, I've further optimized the function to return a single string containing the reversed number.

Comment: thank you for the solution

Comment: Note that this isn't very "optimized" because it works with strings (and string concadinations) instead of numbers.

Comment: @dan1st in terms of clarity and simplicity I would consider it very much optimized compared to the other solutions. Integer cast to strings and even vice versa will have negligible performance impact, even for larger inputs. Also, since the OP wanted a solution where they print the result as a String, it seems natural for the function to return a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.  You only need to pass the value you are reversing. The  math computation computes 10 to the power of the number of digits in the argument.

```
public static int reverse(int v) {
    int reversed = 0;
    if (v > 0) {
        int d = (int)Math.pow(10,(int)(Math.log10(v)));
        reversed = reverse(v%d) * 10 + v/d;
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Of course, if you can pass a second argument as a scratch pad, then it can be done like so.  As you tear down the original value you build up the returned value.

```
public static int reverse(int v, int reversed) {
    if (v > 0) {
        return reverse(v / 10, reversed * 10 + v % 10);
    }
    return reversed;
}
```